# Force an App to Open Full Screen in a Specific Desktop Space

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control, fullscreen

I'm running Mavericks OS X 10.9

As the title suggests I would like to force an app to open in full screen in a specific desktop space.

I can get an app to always open full screen, then position the app in the desired desktop space.

However, when I close the app and reopen, it will always open as the right most desktop space.

Any one have any ideas as to how I may address this?

Comment: How do you get the app to always open full screen?

Comment: Open the app and set it to full screen. After you quit/close the app, it will reopen full screen. Which is by design and seems to work pretty consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences, Mission Control, and untick "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use"

This has worked for me for the last 10 minutes

Comment: have you tried positioning the app fullscreen furthest to the left? If I then close the app and reopen it it wont reappear in that same position.

Answer (score 0):

*[Very late answer, but this is an absolute]*
Fullscreen apps go to the right. That's how they work. If you want them in specific Spaces, don't use fullscreen.